# Correct way to get data from incrementally named columns with sqlite

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

I have a SQLite table wherein the columns are named incrementally (`COLUMN_HERB_1`, `COLUMN_HERB_2` ... `COLUMN_HERB_20`). For each relevant row I want to go through each column and work with the data in the same way for each so looping through them would make the most sense to me.

The problem I am having is that the following returns the error:

```
'java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: column 'HerbalDatabaseContract.SavedRxs.COLUMN_HERB_1' does not exist':

    int i = 1;
    String cursorString = "HerbalDatabaseContract.SavedRxs.COLUMN_HERB_" + i;
    String herb = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(cursorString));
```

But the following works perfectly (which seems to contradict the above error):

```
String herb = cursor2.getString(cursor2.getColumnIndexOrThrow(HerbalDatabaseContract.SavedRxs.COLUMN_HERB_1));
```

What am I missing and what is the correct way to go about this?

EDIT: The table is defined here:

```
public static abstract class SavedRxs implements BaseColumns {
public static final String TABLE_NAME = "SavedRxsTable";
public static final String COLUMN_PATIENT_ID = "PatientID";
public static final String COLUMN_DATETIME = "DateAndTime";
public static final String COLUMN_WEEKS = "WeeksAmount";
public static final String COLUMN_DOSES = "DailyDoses";;
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_1 = "Herb1";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_2 = "Herb2";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_3 = "Herb3";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_4 = "Herb4";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_5 = "Herb5";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_6 = "Herb6";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_7 = "Herb7";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_8 = "Herb8";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_9 = "Herb9";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_10 = "Herb10";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_11 = "Herb11";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_12 = "Herb12";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_13 = "Herb13";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_14 = "Herb14";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_15 = "Herb15";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_16 = "Herb16";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_17 = "Herb17";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_18 = "Herb18";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_19 = "Herb19";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_20 = "Herb20";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_1_AMOUNT = "Herb1Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_2_AMOUNT = "Herb2Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_3_AMOUNT = "Herb3Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_4_AMOUNT = "Herb4Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_5_AMOUNT = "Herb5Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_6_AMOUNT = "Herb6Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_7_AMOUNT = "Herb7Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_8_AMOUNT = "Herb8Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_9_AMOUNT = "Herb9Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_10_AMOUNT = "Herb10Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_11_AMOUNT = "Herb11Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_12_AMOUNT = "Herb12Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_13_AMOUNT = "Herb13Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_14_AMOUNT = "Herb14Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_15_AMOUNT = "Herb15Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_16_AMOUNT = "Herb16Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_17_AMOUNT = "Herb17Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_18_AMOUNT = "Herb18Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_19_AMOUNT = "Herb19Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_HERB_20_AMOUNT = "Herb20Amount";
public static final String COLUMN_ROWS_VISIBLE = "RowsVisible";
public static final String COLUMN_IS_DISPENSED = "IsDispensed";

public static final String TEXT_TYPE = " TEXT";
public static final String COMMA_SEP = ",";
public static final String SQL_CREATE_ENTRIES =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_NAME + " (" +
                _ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY," +
                COLUMN_PATIENT_ID + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_DATETIME + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_WEEKS + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_DOSES + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_1 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_2 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_3 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_4 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_5 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_6 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_7 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_8 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_9 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_10 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_11 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_12 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_13 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_14 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_15 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_16 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_17 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_18 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_19 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_20 + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_1_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_2_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_3_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_4_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_5_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_6_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_7_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_8_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_9_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_10_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_11_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_12_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_13_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_14_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_15_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_16_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_17_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_18_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_19_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_HERB_20_AMOUNT + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_ROWS_VISIBLE + TEXT_TYPE + COMMA_SEP +
                COLUMN_IS_DISPENSED + TEXT_TYPE + " )";
```

Comment: Show the definition of `HerbalDatabaseContract.SavedRxs.COLUMN_HERB_1`.

Comment: I've edited my post, does that give you the info you need? (Sorry, am new to both programming and stackoverflow!)

Comment: The correct way is to structure the database so you have one row per herb per entity, rather than trying to treat a set of columns like an array.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Thanks for your reply. Currently each herb contained within a row corresponds to a different part of a blend, with each different row being a different blend, and with there being many different blends in one table. To separate each component of a blend in to separate rows as you suggest would require each herb to have more information associated with it to define exactly which blend it was from and where abouts in that blend it was. Would this not hugely increase the size of the database and the time it takes to reassemble the data?

Comment: @MarkJ . . . That is called a junction table and it is the right way to structure the database.  You should have a table for blends (one row per blend), a table for herbs (describing the herb), and a junction table, BlendsHerbs, with one row per blend and one row per herb.

Comment: Thanks @GordonLinoff, I'll certainly look into doing things that way. As I already have a few users of this app with data stored in its current way even copying the data into a new format could benefit from looping through the current columns rather than typing them all out, but as it wasn't designed for this is this then not an option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@GordonLinoff is precisely correct, relational databases are designed to optimise 1 to many relationships.  They are not designed to handle exactly 20, because what happens when you need 21 or 25 or more - then you need to rewrite all of queries again.  Proper relational database design will mean the queries will not need to change based on how much data you have.

I Answered a very similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25153966/strategy-to-map-multiple-filed-in-a-single-table-to-a-single-field-in-another-ta/25154374#25154374).

The first thing to do is correct identify your nouns and verbs in what you are trying to achieve. The above post spelled it out nicely in his first sentence, so I will take a stab at what you are representing here.

- "...need to record the **dosage** of **herbs** prescribed to a **patient**..."

The **Patients** and **Herbs** become data tables that store information about each entity.

The **Dosage** or **Prescription** becomes the relationship table as it is the verb, so you are recording what happened at a point in time.  Your proposed Dosage table should look something like:

```
COLUMN DOSAGE_ID - simply a unique key for the database to easily find the correct record to update
COLUMN_PATIENT_ID - link to a patient table
COLUMN_DATETIME
COLUMN_WEEKS
COLUMN_DOSES
COLUMN_HERB_ID - link to a herb table, if as you suggest the herbs are actually a recipe, not a single herb, then see below.
COLUMN_HERB_AMOUNT
```

Multiple records are then easily returned for a patient by selecting from the database where the PATIENT_ID = param.  It also means different doses, start dates, duration can all be assigned separately for each different herb.

The answer to the recipe question is to create 2 extra tables. The first one simply provides a name and description for the **recipe** and the second will define the **ingredient** using relationship as in the Dosage table. ie

**Recipe table**

```
COLUMN_RECIPE_ID
COLUMN_RECIPE_NAME
COLUMN_RECIPE_NOTES
```

**Ingredient table**

```
COLUMN_INGREDIENT_ID
COLUMN_RECIPE_ID - reference to recipe table
COLUMN_HERB_ID - reference to herb table
COLUMN_HERB_AMOUNT
```

Comment: Many thanks for this simo, it also solves a couple of other problems I was facing due to poor database design, not least the time it was taking to extract data for the total usage of each herb in a different part of the app.