# Strategy to map multiple filed in a single table to a single field in another table

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I am creating a database where different properties of a single object are measured via different sources. I have a table containing list of sources along with source description and source ID. I want to create a table which will list which source I am going to use for which particular measurement for a particular object. So in this table I will have a field for objectID and the propertys which I am going to measure. For each property I want to map a sourceID. The following diagram describes my design
[image]

I would like to know what kind of mapping will I have in this case?
It appears to me that I will have to map each individual property column in Object table to sourceID in source table. With this I will have multiple 1:n mappings. Is that alright? 
I am using MySQL workbench. Please tell if this can be designed in a better way.

**EDIT#1**
For each object I would like to query which is the source for a particular "property" field. After getting this info, I will log data for that particular property in a different table using the given source.

Comment: It really depends entirely on how you plan to query the data. You just have to make sure you add indexes appropriate for how you use it, and that none of your queries are too slow. If a query is too slow, use EXPLAIN to determine if indexing can fix it. If indexing can't fix it, then you can try reorganizing or denormalizing data. But the structure you proposed should be perfect for a lot of use cases. Without more details, there's not much to say about how this will perform.

Comment: A mapping like that is not inherently inefficient in any way, and for certain use cases it is the most efficient.

Comment: @BenLee can you specifically suggest the best way to map in this case?

Comment: My point is, the best way depends on how you use it. You haven't specified the case fully.

Comment: @BenLee Please check now.

Answer (score 2):

If you look at your first statement

"...properties of a single **object** are **measured** via different **sources**..."

you can actually see straight away that you are probably looking for 3 tables. The **Source** table you propose looks fine. I suggest that **Object** table though look more like

```
ObjectId
ObjectName
ObjectDescription
... other object details (except measurement)
```

Your third table is your **Measurement** table, which could conceivably look like this

```
MeasurementId
ObjectId - reference to Object table
SourceId - reference to Source table
DatePerformed
MeasurementValue
Success 
Notes  etc
```

The benefits here are

- That you don't need to have a specific column in your **Object** for a specific **Source**. This becomes very difficult to maintain if you suddenly have more sources.
- Not all **Objects** need a value for each **Source**, although with this structure you can still determine if an Object is missing Measurement from a particular source easily as well.
- You can have multiple measurements stored for an object (separated via the DatePerformed), and using Max(DatePerformed) you can retrieve the latest measurement.

Then you can get a list of results, if you then do

```
SELECT ObjectId, SourceId, DatePerformed, MeasurementValue
FROM Measurement
WHERE ObjectId = <your Object>
[AND/OR] SourceId = <your source>
```

Comment: Talking about the benefits as you mentioned, If I have more sources, the number of entries is source table will increase(no new column will be added). If I have more properties to be mentioned, I can add an extra column in my object table. How hard is it to add an extra column?

Comment: @bubble adding extra columns to tables is very easy, but if based on your original solution that each Source is represented by a specific property field in the Object table, then when you add your new Source, you will have to update all of you SQL queries to include the specific check for that field. Using the Measurement table in the middle means that access is parameterised, i.e. you simply pass in a different SourceId to your existing query, instead of re-writing it.